# Edit 2D array instance variable size without Array List (image manipulation)

Tags: java, arrays

I need to edit the original instance variable `private in[][] pixels;` to be twice the width, I've done the algorithm to mirror the image and make a new array twice as wide I just don't know how to set the original `int[][]` pixels to it. The pixels array has to be the one modified, it can't go by another name.

```
    private int[][] pixels;
    ...

    if(transformationName == "Mirror"){

        int[][] mirrorTemp = new int[height][width*2];

        for(int h = 0; h < height; h++){

            for(int w = 0; w < width; w++){

                mirrorTemp[h][w] = pixels[h][w];
                mirrorTemp[h][w + width] = pixels[h][width - h - 1];
            }
        }

        int[][] pixels = new int[height][width*2];

        for(int h = 0; h < height; h++){

            for(int w = 0; w < (width*2); w++){

                pixels[h][w] = mirrorTemp[h][w];
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I believe the following is what you intended to do.

```
    for(int h = 0; h < height; h++){
        for(int w = 0; w < width; w++){
            mirrorTemp[h][w] = pixels[h][w];
            mirrorTemp[h][w + width] = pixels[h][width - w];
        }
    }
```

After this, you can simply

```
    pixels = mirrorTemp;
```

since the two are both `int[][]` type.

Hope this helps.